# Best way to filter out okara from soymilk without hurting hands/wrist?

Tags: soymilk, filtering

My job requires me to be on a keyboard for most of the time. This means my wrists/hands ache quite a bit, even with medication. I do like to make soymilk but I find the process of filtering okara through a cheesecloth quite strenuous, even taxing on my poor hands.

What methods are best for filtering okara from soymilk without having to go through the process of squeezing and straining a cheesecloth to filter it out?

Answer (score 1):

On the *low tech/cost versions exist* side a cheese, wine, or cider press. You're still squeezing and straining the milk from the okara, but you're not doing it directly by hand.

On the *high-tech/high-cost probably impractical* side, a centrifuge.

Comment: I'm not familiar with them as a gadget I've never bought, but I suppose some of the mechanical "juicer" appliances *might* do the job?

Comment: although presses usually have some sort of a screw to apply pressure, you might be able to do some of the work by just putting heavy things on top of the bag

Comment: Some use screws, some use levers, some use a hydrualic jack. Lever types can amplify weight applied by pressing close to the pivot and pulling or weighting further from the pivot. Screw types can use a long lever handle for the screw.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yes, juicers can make soy milk and nut milks. At least the masticating juicers usually include it in their feature list. It would be an interesting mid-tech, mid-cost solution. Since the OP has a wrist pain condition, they should first think about the cleaning aspect too, before investing in a masticating juicer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your normal process is, but I've seen a recommendation to cook the ground soybeans before straining them. It's supposed to make the straining process much easier than doing it the other way around.